# Fatal Exception: Unable to Start Activity Component Info

Tags: android

I'm new to Android app development and right now I'm trying to make a simple calculator app. The compiler doesn't detect any errors and it downloads to the phone successfully, but when ran it gets a bunch of runtime errors.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button one; 
Button two;
Button three; 
Button four;
Button five;
Button six;
Button seven;
Button eight;
Button nine;
Button add;
Button sub;
Button multiply;
Button divide;
Button clear;
Button equals;
String calculateNumber;
TextView textRead;
boolean ADD = false;
boolean SUB = false;
boolean MULTIPLY = false;
boolean DIVIDE = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //references all the objects within the XML file
    one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.One);
    two = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Two);
    three = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Three);
    four = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Four);
    five = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Five);
    six= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Six);
    seven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Seven);
    eight= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Eight);
    nine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Nine);
    add= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add);
    sub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sub);
    multiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Multiply);
    divide= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Divide);
    equals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Equal);
    textRead = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Numbers);

    //Action listeners for each button to add it to the string
    one.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "1";
            textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
        } 
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "2";
            textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
        }
    });


    three.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "3";
            textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
        }
    });

    four.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "4";
            textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
        }
    });

    five.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "5";
            textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
        }
    });

    six.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "6";
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    seven.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "7";
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    eight.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "8";
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    nine.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + "9";
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    add.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + " + ";
                ADD = true;
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + " - ";
                SUB = true;
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    multiply.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + " x ";
                MULTIPLY = true;
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    divide.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = calculateNumber + " / ";
                DIVIDE = true;
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    clear.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateNumber = "";
                ADD = false;
                SUB = false;
                MULTIPLY = false;
                DIVIDE = false;
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });

    equals.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //splits the one large string into two strings that can be parsable into Ints
                String[] bothNumbers = calculateNumber.split("\\+");

                double numberOne = 0;
                double numberTwo = 0;

                numberOne =  Double.parseDouble(bothNumbers[0]); 
                numberTwo =  Double.parseDouble(bothNumbers[1]); 

                if(ADD = true)
                    {
                    calculateNumber = "" + (numberOne+numberTwo);
                    ADD = false;
                    }

                else if(SUB = true)
                    {
                    calculateNumber = "" + (numberOne - numberTwo);
                    SUB = false;
                    }

                else if (MULTIPLY = true)
                    {
                    calculateNumber = "" + (numberOne*numberTwo);
                    MULTIPLY = false;
                    }

                else if (DIVIDE = true)
                    {
                    calculateNumber = "" + (numberOne/numberTwo);
                    DIVIDE = false;
                    }
                textRead.setText(calculateNumber);
            }
         });
}
```

}

This is my one Java file where the action listeners are for the buttons. It shouldn't have any problems because they're only called when the buttons are pressed.

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.cakculator.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here are the errors that eclipse gave me

```
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cakculator/com.example.cakculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at com.example.cakculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:152) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4486) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931) 
06-20 10:48:16.678: E/AndroidRuntime(25231):    ... 11 more
```

If you guys could help me find the thing causing the errors, that would much appreciated!

Comment: What is line 152 in `MainActivity`?

Comment: You forgot to set `clear`.

Answer (score 4):

`Button clear` is not set -> NPE.

Comment: This was the problem, much appreciated!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you look at the top of the stack trace but can't find anything obvious, go all the way down to the first exception, and that's usually the clue.
And please accept the answer if it fixes your problem.